# Everything centred in android UI XML and still doesn't show in centre in device but it's snapped towards the left side

Tags: android

Hi I've been trying to debug this UI XML for android it's looking centered in the IntelliJ idea but when I run this on my phone then it doesn't centred and the whole layout is snapped to the left side of the device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Connection State"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/connection_status_button"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:text="Connecting"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Amount to deliver:"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview_amount_to_deliver"
        android:text="100 litres"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tank Level"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textview_tank_level"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="11.50 Litres"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delivered"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textview_delivered_fuel"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="11.50 Litres"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/finish_refill_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    android:text="Finish Refill"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was in a fragment layout, the activity layout had wrap content so everything was getting wrapped inside a small box inside activity and thus it wasn't working fine. 
Changed the framelayout inside activity to match parent and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your layout to this added `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` to parent layout and its working fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Connection State"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/connection_status_button"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:background="#333333"
            android:text="Connecting"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Amount to deliver:"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textview_amount_to_deliver"
                android:text="100 litres"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tank Level"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/textview_tank_level"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="11.50 Litres"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Delivered"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/textview_delivered_fuel"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="11.50 Litres"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/finish_refill_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Finish Refill"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i'll just check and run and it try if it works , also can you tell me the reason behind this ?

Comment: @AnkitArora i have tested it on my device HTC API 15

Comment: sorry your answer is correct too but the scenario i had was different and that caused the problem

Comment: already did sir, the upvote on your answer is already mine, but it doesn't work. i've answered the question myself after identifying the problem

Answer (score 1):

It's great you've solved the issue but you've added unnecessary gravity attributes in your XML.

Here is a simplified code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Connection State"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connection_status_button"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:text="Connecting"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Amount to deliver:"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_amount_to_deliver"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="100 litres"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tank Level"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textview_tank_level"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="11.50 Litres"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delivered"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textview_delivered_fuel"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="11.50 Litres"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/finish_refill_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Finish Refill" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your android:gravity="center" to android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal".

The reason is : android:gravity refers to to gravity of the element inside the layout and android:layout_gravity refer to the gravity of the item outside the layout.

Like if in a TextView you set the android:gravity="left" then the text which you set in the TextView will get set from left but if you want your textview to be set in left you have to use android:layout_gravity="left"